# Origin of "Yellow dog Updater, Modified"?

Tags: yum, history

Everywhere it is said that `yum` is "Yellow dog Updater, Modified". But Google-ing all around can't find me the origin, possibly "Yellow dog Updater (unmodified)". As opposed to this, the origin of Advanced Packaging Tool (`apt`) is directly available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool). As of today, Yellow Dog Linux is a very uncommon Linux distro, even rarer than OpenSUSE, so info about YDL is hard to find. I'm curious about this.
Can anyone tell me the history of `yum`?

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowdog_Updater,_Modified) page on the topic gives a fairly detailed history, with pointers to reference documents — isn’t that detailed enough for you?

Comment: In particular it's made clear that yum was written from scratch, but in imitation of `yup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yum evolved from Yellow dog updater (aka "Yup") which was part of the Yellow dog linux distribution for Macintosh computers. yup ran only on Yellow dog (Macintosh) systems. See the following:

https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=F1FquvLFolIC&pg=PT77&lpg=PT77&dq=why+is+yum+called+yellow&source=bl&ots=RgszYQY0h5&sig=siPvWb67n6x4o_1Mhv3TrOs-gGY&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiRgOzt-JfTAhVEsxQKHd9JDacQ6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=why%20is%20yum%20called%20yellow&f=false

Comment: That link isn’t available in many countries...